# Set equal vertical margins to any block element at once

Tags: css, css-selectors

By default, most browsers will add a top and bottom margin of `1em` to many block elements, like `ol`, `ul`, `blockquote`, `h1`, `h2`, etc.

Is there any short and clever selector that can change theses vertical margins (let say to `1.45em`) all at once, without having to list every element in the CSS file?

**Note:** This question have been marked as a [duplicate.] But I am not trying to select all block elements by their properties (which I know is imposible in CSS), nor do I want to select all block elements by listing them one by one. I am concern in creating an equal vertical (top and bottom) margin in all elements that by default create a new line, by using the simplest selector posible.

Comment: I do not believe the question is a duplicate. The question and the posible answers are about setting an equal margins for block elements, although this does not mean that one need to *select* neither *target* all those block elements at once (actually, the question specifically ask for a way to achieve this without listing all instances of blocks elements). For example, I recently encounter the *Lobotomized Owls* technique, which can be a great solution for this question. Please, consider reopen this question.

Comment: *actually, the question specifically ask for a way to achieve this without listing all instances of blocks elements* --> and the *perfect* duplicate is giving you the answer: *This is not possible with CSS; you can't select an element based on one of its CSS properties.* ... The issue is not setting the margin but selecting the elements. If you are able to select the elements then setting the margin is trivial.

Comment: *The issue is not setting the margin but selecting the elements [with `display:block` property]*. Not necessarily. For example, one simple solution I found was to use the Universal Selector and apply a top and bottom margin (inline elements will not be affected by vertical margins). Notice that I did that without selecting any block element (or selecting elements based on their properties [which I know is not posible in CSS]). My question was clear, to accomplish equal vertical margins in elements with `display:block`, not to select elements based on their properties.

Comment: eh *to accomplish equal vertical margins in elements with display:block* ---> this mean you want *to select* elements based on *their property* which is display being block so : *to select elements based on their properties*

Comment: I don't want to *select* these elements, I actually selected **all** elements using the Universal Selector solution (even if the Universal Selector also selects those that display block, of course). But the question is not about selecting elements by their properties, but instead about clever and short solutions for setting an equal vertical margin without selecting all instance of the elements.

Comment: In the CSS world there is two things: (1) selecting elements (2) applying styles. You cannot do one without this other. If you are dealing with CSS you need *to select elements*. You cannot set margin to ... nothing

Comment: Of course. But that is not the point. The point is that my question does not try to select elements by their properties (the reason why it was closed). My question ask for ways to set custom vertical margins to all block elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found so far is to use the Universal Selector:

```css
:root {
  --custom-vertical-margin: 1.5rem;
}

* {
  margin-top: var(--custom-vertical-margin);
  margin-bottom: var(--custom-vertical-margin);
}
```

Even though the Universal Selector will also target inline elements, these are not and will not be affected by vertical margins.

This accomplishes what the question is about: **to set equal vertical margins on any block element at once**, *without having to list every element* [with `display:block` property] in the CSS file, nor by trying to target elements by their properties (which is imposible in CSS).

Comment: This will affect inline-block elements, float elements, positionned element, iframe, canvas, img and let's don't forget the html and body element. It will also apply to all flexbox item, CSS grid item ... the list can be even bigger

Comment: Yes! Good point. Another way to see it is that the solution will apply to all elements (is the Universal Selector after all), except to `inline` elements.

Comment: img are considered as inline element (inline replaced element to be more accurate) so saying *except inline elements* is wrong.